# snort log file format

Tags: logging, snort

In /etc/sysconfig/snort I've commented following line:
"#BINARY_LOG=1"
The log file in 
/usr/local/snort/var/log/eth0
is still generated but it can not be read in Wireshark and it's not ascii as well.
How this file can be read?

Answer (score 1):

There's not too much information to go on here, but I'm guessing that you're logging unified2 files, which will need to be processed by a program called barnyard2.  Please download that here: http://www.securixlive.com/barnyard2/

Barnyard2 reads the unified2 files and can log them to local and/or remote databases, including mysql, mssql, and postgres.

Also, if you downloaded the snort source package, there should be a tool included named u2spewfoo.  This is a parser for unified2 files, and will output their contents to your screen.  This helps to ensure that the file being logged is indeed a unified2 file.  Hope this helps!